# Splitting pdf file pages from middle of each page into two pages

Tags: pdf, ubuntu

I wonder how to split a pdf file pages from middle of each page into two pages ([See here for reference](https://askubuntu.com/q/56853/283472)). In past I was using `pdfscissor` in `Windows 7` and `Gscan2pdf` and  `ScanTailor` in `Ubuntu 14.04`. Now I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04` and both `Gscan2pdf` and  `ScanTailor` can split only image files. I wonder if there is a way to split a  pdf file pages from middle of each page  into two pages. Thanks

**Edited** (2017-09-20)

*Solution*

On Linux first install `mupdf-tools`

```
sudo apt-get install mupdf-tools
```

Then use

```
mutool poster -x 2 -y 2 input.pdf output.pdf
```

Comment: what do you mean by "from middle" ? From middle of the page? or middle of file? Can you give a specific example, such as "I would like to put pages 1 through 5 in one file, and 6 through 13 in another file" ? I am going to suggest you use `pdftk`

Comment: @scottkosty: Please see my edits. Yes, I remember I used `pdftk` in past but forgot the command. Would appreciate if you help me. Thanks

Comment: \includepicture can crop off the right half for one page, then the left half for another page (two separate calls).

Comment: you want do this using (La)TeX?

Comment: @Closevoters, please give the OP some time to respond. OP, as much as we love PDF 'round these parts, the question really does have involve TeX in some way :)

Comment: @SeanAllred: I doubt that. One can not easily _split_ a PDF page. In TeX you can only include it twice and move the viewpoint.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Please see [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56853/splitting-a-pdf-page-in-two) for reference.

Comment: @MartinSchröder that's the basic idea, of course: include the pdf twice with different bounding boxes. this can certainly be wrapped in a macro.

Comment: @MYaseen208 I don't think Martin was saying that it's hard to split a PDF in general (for instance, I bet imagemagick makes this a breeze) -- I think he was merely saying it's non-intuitive to do *from TeX* (which is true).

Comment: @SeanAllred: I'm talking about really splitting the content of a PDF _page_. That easy for bitmaps, but quite hard for the general case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is a simple example that illustrates how to use LaTex to produce a new PDF by dividing the first page of a source PDF document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}    % To import the PDF document
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1,trim=0 0 400 0, clip]{document_name.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=1,trim=400 0 0 0, clip]{document_name.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Here is a more complicated example that allows you to process a multi-page PDF document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}   % To import PDF documents
\usepackage{pgffor}     % To easily create loops

% A 'variable' containing the name of the source document
\newcommand{\documentName}{document_name.pdf}

% A 'variable' containing the number of pages in the source document
\pdfximage{\documentName}
\newcommand{\lastPage}{\the\pdflastximagepages}

\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {1,...,\lastPage}{
    \includepdf[pages=\n,trim=0 0 148.5mm 0, clip]{\documentName}
    \includepdf[pages=\n,trim=148.5mm 0 0 0, clip]{\documentName}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @touhami for your answer. You are splitting pages vertically, how about splitting pages horizontally as well as vertically and horizontally?

Comment: @MYaseen208 try this for horizontal `\includepdf[pages=1,trim=0 100 0 0, clip,landscape]{doc1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=1,trim=0 0 0 100, clip,landscape]{doc1.pdf}` and you can continu

Comment: @MYaseen208 Just remember that you can easily wrap this approach in a macro to make sure your clippings are always exact :)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179398/176060 is a good solution.