# extract two 2 A5 pages from 1 A4 page

Tags: pdf, extract

I have a pdf with 14 A4 (Landscape) pages, each of which consists of 2 A5 (Portrait) pages.
I need to print this for an old lady whose sight is somewhat impaired. So I need to enlarge the text so that, say each original A5 (half of an A4 page) gets the size of an A4 page.

In principle, I need to extract the two A5 pages from each A4 page, so I can manipulate (enlarge) them afterwards.

I know only of doing the opposite: putting two A5 pages on one A4

I am using latest TeXLive in Xubuntu 18.04

Can somebody give me a hint (or better: a solution)?

Comment: Do you have the (LaTeX ?) source file of this PDF ? Or do you tant ton use LaTeX to post process a generic PDF ? Could you please providence a MWE of what you have tryed up to now ?

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257306/2388

Answer (score 1):

@Jhor: No, only the PDF. No MWE, as I hoped it could be solved with pdfjam or so.

@Ulrike: Thanks, just before I saw your hint, I encountered that page.

On

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12482/split-pages-in-pdf/179398#179398

I found among other solutions a really simple answer:

```
mutool poster -x 2 input.pdf output.pdf
```

mutool is in mupdf/mupdf-tool in the standard ubuntu repository